# Why more Android applications (compared to iOS) use certificate pinning?

Tags: certificates, mobile, android, certificate-pinning

I used `mitmproxy` to test the same 50 apps on iOS and Android and noticed that more than 50% of the Android applications compared to 23% of iOS, used certificate pinning.

Is there any explanation as to why more Android applications use certificate pinning?

Comment: https://xkcd.com/552/ maybe? What kinds of apps were you testing? Were they self-signed certificates?

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara I tested the same applications in iOS and android and they were from many different categories :)

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara what does it matter if they're self-signed if they're pinned?

Comment: @NeilMcGuigan they'd be more interested in pinning if they're self-signed than if they rely on PKI.

Comment: Pinning examples more readily available for Android than for iOS?

Comment: @Ángel that could be an explanation.. Do you have any literature examples that I could use to support this ? Thanks